# How to get Proxy values back to type-level?

Tags: haskell

It's hard to ask this question because I don't know the exact terminology to be used in this situation. I'll to try express myself through the exact problem I'm facing:

The `gogol` set of libraries have a bunch of permissions exposed at the type-level through the use of [`Proxy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol-sheets-0.3.0/docs/Network-Google-Sheets-Types.html#g:2)
- A number of functions in `gogol` are polymorphic over this "permission list", for example, [`newEnv`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gogol-0.3.0/docs/Network-Google-Env.html#v:newEnv), who's function signature looks like the following, where `s` is supposed to be a list of these proxies.

```
newEnv :: (MonadIO m, MonadCatch m, AllowScopes s) => m (Env s)
```

Now, here's how one is supposed to provide this `s` type-level parameter:

```
import Network.Google (allow, (!), newEnv, Env)
import Network.Google.Sheets (driveScope, spreadsheetsScope)


type MyScopes = '[ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
                 , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
                 ]

myEnv :: (MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => Env MyScopes
mEnv = Network.Google.allow (driveScope ! spreadsheetScope) newEnv

-- or --

myEnv :: (MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => Env MyScopes
mEnv = Network.Google.allow (Proxy :: Proxy MyScopes) newEnv
```

Notice the duplication in that code snippet above? Even though the `gogol` library provides `driveScope` and `spreadsheetsScope`, I am being forced to type them out again. Is there any way to do the conceptual equivalent of the following:

```
myEnv :: (MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => Env (driveScope ! spreadsheetScope)
```

Comment: Why not just leave off the type signature?

Comment: @melpomene not clear how that would help.

Comment: Probably no way short of TH. They really should have exposed type synonyms instead of (or in addition to) proxies throughout the whole library.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible - you can't access the type of a declared value in the way you want.

As @Daniel Wagner commented, the libraries should export type synonyms - you could make a pull request to [the repository](https://github.com/brendanhay/gogol), but this style is used across all the various libraries, so it might be a bit of work.

An alternative, if you don't mind having a copy of the types locally, would be to do some type-level programming to avoid the repetition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, TypeApplications #-}

...
import Network.Gogol.Auth.Scope (Nub, (++))

-- Type-level append, used by !
type family a !! b where
    xs !! ys = Nub (xs ++ ys)

myEnv :: (MonadIO m, MonadCatch m) => Env (DriveScope !! SpreadsheetScope)
-- Here, @ just lets you pass in type parameters that don't appear in the body
mEnv = Network.Google.allow (Proxy @(DriveScope !! SpreadsheetScope)) newEnv

type DriveScope = '[...]
type SpreadsheetScope = '[...]
```

But that still does mean repeating them yourself.